# Pre-filter condition - deep-diff Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, deep-diff

I use the deep-diff Node.js library for comparison of two JSONs. There is also pre-filter condition for omitting few fields for comparison. If my pre-filter condition is multiple attributes, how would I specify that? In the given example, the pre-filter attribute is `name`. If I want to add one or more attributes, how would I specify that. Thanks in advance.

```
var diff = require('deep-diff').diff;

        var lhs = {
            name: 'my object',
            description: 'it\'s an object!',
            details: {
                it: 'has',
                an: 'array',
                with: ['a', 'few', 'elements']
            }
        };

        var rhs = {
            name: 'updated object',
            description: 'it\'s not an object!',
            details: {
                it: 'has',
                an: 'array',
                with: ['a', 'few', 'more', 'elements', {
                    than: 'before'
                }]
            }
        };


        var differences = diff(lhs, rhs, function(path, key) {

            return key === 'name';
        });

        console.log(differences);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then it should be as simple as adding an or (`||`). For example, do ignore description as well you could write:

```
var differences = diff(lhs, rhs, function(path, key) {
    return key === 'name' || key === 'description'; 
});
```

Of course, as you start ignoring lots of items you may want to introduce an array of properties / paths you want to ignore and then simply check in the pre-filter if the current property should be ignored. So a more generic way with an array could be like this:

```
var ignoredProperties = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'];
var differences = diff(lhs, rhs, function(path, key) {
    return ignoredProperties.indexOf(key) >= 0;
});
```

With ECMAScript 2016 there are also [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) objects which would be better in this case but as this is not widely implemented yet I would use the code above.

Comment: can you help me doing this in a more generic way instead of giving it a hard coded value, say passing a function of array of values. TIA

Comment: var inputArray = ["name", "description"];
var differences = diff(lhs, rhs, function(path, key) {
    var truthValue = false;
    for (var i in inputArray) {
        if (key === i) {
            truthValue = true;
        }
    }
    return truthValue;
});

Comment: why I am not getting the key. I am only getting the path value in diff